# Getting undefined values from subscribing to BehaviorSubject returned as Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5

So I want to put the name of the currently logged in user in the header. Right now, I can do it with login but if ever I refresh the page, I will lost the value which I found out is a normal behavior in SPA.(The data is still in the local storage though) So I created a function that would get again the currently logged in user in local storage and store it in my auth service. I'm doing this in the ngOnInit() of header component. However, I am getting undefined values. From what I understand, it should return the last value since I am subscribed to it. Besides, I am re-assigning the values first before I get it from the service.

**auth service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { CurrentUserInterface } from '../interfaces/current-user.interface';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
private rootUrl = 'testapi.com';

private currentUser = new BehaviorSubject<CurrentUserInterface>();
private isAuthorized: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

setCurrentUser(): void {
    if(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")) {
        this.currentUser.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")));
        this.isAuthorized.next(true);
    }
    else {
        this.isAuthorized.next(false);
    }
    console.log(this.currentUser.value); **//HAS VALUES**
}

getCurrentUser(): Observable<CurrentUserInterface> {
    return this.currentUser.asObservable();
}

checkAuth(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isAuthorized.asObservable();
}
}
```

**header component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    import { AuthenticationService } from '../_shared/services/authentication.service';

    import { CurrentUserInterface } from '../_shared/interfaces/current-user.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  private currentUser = new Observable<CurrentUserInterface>;
  private isAuthorized: Observable<boolean> = false;

  constructor(private router: Router,
      private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.authenticationService.setCurrentUser();
      this.isAuthorized = this.authenticationService.checkAuth()
      .subscribe(
          isAuthorized => {
              this.isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );

      this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser()
      .subscribe(
          currentUser => {
              this.currentUser = currentUser;
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );

      console.log(this.currentUser.value); **// UNDEFINED**
      console.log(this.isAuthorized.value); **// UNDEFINED**
   }

   logout() {
          this.authenticationService.logout();
          this.router.navigate(['../login'], { relativeTo: this.route });
   }

}
```

Comment: You don't set an initial value for the BehaviorSubject

Comment: Why not? I have seen various examples where they had default values.

Comment: The `.next` on `setCurrentUser` won't apply until the next event loop, _after_ `console.log(this.currentUser.value)`

Comment: uhhh I'm getting values on that console log though.

Comment: In your question it says they're `undefined`

Comment: There are two more console.log in ngOnInit of header component and that's where I'm getting undefined values.

Comment: Those were the ones I was talking about

Comment: NEVER this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser (). Subscribe (..), NEVER this.isAuthorized = this.authenticationService.checkAuth (). Why you equal a variable to an Observable (only makes sense if you want to cancel your subscription) ?

Comment: Moreover, you are changing "Authorization" before you subscribe to the observable and you are make console.log out of subscribe. That's never work

Comment: There's so much bad code above, I wonder if it's been tested properly before posting.

Comment: `private isAuthorized: Observable<boolean> = false;` does not work

Comment: `console.log(this.currentUser.value);` does not work.

Comment: Eric, All the code you've pointed works though. Btw I fixed my problem by removing this.isAuthorized = this.authenticationService ... like what Eliseo said.

Comment: You are putting your console.log calls after the subscribe. This whole thing is asynchronous, so you have to put the console.log calls inside the onNext handler of the subscribe. There is no point in assigning this.currentUser to the observable, only assign this.currentUser inside the onNext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a RESULT of an observable to the observable itself. that's what you have:

`private currentUser = new Observable<CurrentUserInterface>;`

then

```
this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser() //<====== here
      .subscribe(
          currentUser => {
              this.currentUser = currentUser; //<========= and here
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );
```

And also, the console.log will run before you even get your response.

try this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../_shared/services/authentication.service';

import { CurrentUserInterface } from '../_shared/interfaces/current-user.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  private currentUser: CurrentUserInterface;
  private isAuthorized: Observable<boolean> = false;

  constructor(private router: Router,
      private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.authenticationService.setCurrentUser();
      this.isAuthorized = this.authenticationService.checkAuth()
      .subscribe(
          isAuthorized => {
              this.isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );

      this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser()
      .subscribe(
          currentUser => {
              this.currentUser = currentUser;
              console.log(this.currentUser);  //<====== console.log here
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );
   }

   logout() {
          this.authenticationService.logout();
          this.router.navigate(['../login'], { relativeTo: this.route });
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed version of your HeaderComponent ngOnInit(). Please be aware that calls to HTTP services are asynchronous. Command flow only continues inside the onNext, onError or onComplete handlers. Any code directly after a subscribe call is executed before the service makes any calls to the observable. In your case, this.currentUser.value for example was undefined since you assigned this.currentUser to an observable. An observable does not have the .value property. You can get around those problems altogether by strictly typing your variables.

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.authenticationService.setCurrentUser();
      // removed assignment to this.isAuthorized
      this.authenticationService.checkAuth()
      .subscribe(
          isAuthorized => {
              this.isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );

      // removed assignment to this.currentUser
      this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser()
      .subscribe(
          currentUser => {
              this.currentUser = currentUser;
              // moved console.log calls into onNext handler. They should not be undefined any more unless the .value properties do really not exist. 
              console.log(this.currentUser.value); 
              console.log(this.isAuthorized.value);
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );    

   }
```